# Keep keyboard layout upon inserting external keyboard

Tags: x11, keyboard, udev, keyboard-layout, hot-plug

I have a custom keyboard layout, that I enable using this commands:

```
setxkbmap -verbose us -variant altgr-intl
xmodmap -verbose /home/coub/.myxmodmap
```

This works just fine, the thing is, that when I attach an external keyboard, the attaching will dismiss my settings and set the default "QWERTY". I would like to keep my settings.

I don't know how to disable this fall back to "QWERTY" on attaching, so at least I've tried to set an `udev` rule to enable my settings again. However the environment in `udev` doesn't have access to `Xorg` environment, so the commands fail.

To workaround this I've written a watcher, that uses `inotifywait` to watch a file and then I change this file by writing to it from an `udev` rule. This almost works, when the keyboard is plugged, it loads my settings, but the keys with third modifier, that is <kbd>ALT-gr</kbd>+<kbd>KEY</kbd> gets mapped incorrectly to some weird keys, that I don't have in my setting.

When I change the file (by `echoing` "something" > watched_file) from terminal emulator, it just works and my keyboard setting is loaded properly.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/337411/how-to-permanently-assign-a-different-keyboard-layout-to-a-usb-keyboard has a working solution with udev rules